# How to resolve collision in the ObjectFactory on wsdl2java?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I'm using `CXF` and `wsdl2java` to autogenerate webservice classes.

Problem: somehow the webservice I want to connect to has duplicate names for some elements:

`Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class`

The xsd is like:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://thenamespace">
    <xs:complexType name="ViolatingName">
     ...
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="ViolatingName" nillable="true" type="tns:ViolatingName"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The xsd itself is imported inside the wsdl that is used to autogenerate the jaxb classes like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://imports">
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://path.to.xsd" namespace="http://thenamespace" />
```

I'm trying to cover this using `jaxb-bindings.xml`:

```
<jaxb:bindings    
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"   
    jaxb:version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemalocation="https://path.to.xsd" node="//xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='ViolatingName']">
            <jaxb:property name="ViolatingNameBinding" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Result:

`[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xs:schema" results in empty target node (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.1:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)`

Why is the `node` wrong here? The xsd has a `xs:schema` tag, so why is this failing?

Interesting fact: when I use any xpath tool, download the XSD to my local machine an check the path, then `//xs:schema/xs:element[@name='ViolatingName']` evaluates to the proper tag.

Comment: missing double '//' on xs:schema for the tag bindings..

Comment: I adapted it, also above, but the result is the same...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out I have to apply a renaming/suffix on all `xs:complexType` elements like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://path.to.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type" />
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `jaxb:factoryMethod` instead of `jaxb:property`.

```
<jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='ViolatingName']">
    <jaxb:factoryMethod name="ViolatingName1" />
</jaxb:bindings>
```

An [example of binding](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/gml/3.1.1/src/main/resources/binding.xjb) using `jaxb:factoryMethod`.

Update:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425306/resolving-conflicts-when-generating-code-with-cxf-and-wsdl2java) might help as well.

Comment: Which one? You have listed two - one with the collission and one with empty target node.

Comment: Sorry, I ment the empty target node. The collusion is not displayed because wsdl2java does not reach the point where this exception could occur at all.,

Comment: Please see the update. I guess you're compiling a WSDL so probably wsdl2java needs some special mumbo-jumbo with bindings. Please see the last link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425306/resolving-conflicts-when-generating-code-with-cxf-and-wsdl2java

Answer (score 1):

### Property Binding Declarations

The  binding declaration enables you to customize the binding of an XML schema element to its Java representation as a property. The scope of customization can either be at the definition level or component level depending upon where the  binding declaration is specified.

The syntax for  customizations is:

```
<property      [ name = "propertyName"]
  [ collectionType = "propertyCollectionType" ]
  [ fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty = "true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ generateIsSetMethod = "true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ enableFailFastCheck ="true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ <baseType> ... </baseType> ]
  [ <javadoc> ... </javadoc> ]
</property>

<baseType>
  <javaType> ... </javaType>
</baseType>
```

- name defines the customization value propertyName; it must be a legal Java identifier.
- collectionType defines the customization value propertyCollectionType, which is the collection type for the property. propertyCollectionType if specified, can be either indexed or any fully-qualified class name that implements java.util.List.
- fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty defines the customization value fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty. The value can be either true, false, 1, or 0.
- generateIsSetMethod defines the customization value of generateIsSetMethod. The value can be either true, false, 1, or 0.
  enableFailFastCheck defines the customization value enableFailFastCheck. The value can be either true, false, 1, or 0. Please note that the JAXB implementation does not support failfast validation.
- `<javadoc>` customizes the Javadoc tool annotations for the property's getter method.

From this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)

**XSD**

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://thenamespace">
    <xs:element name="ViolatingName" type="tns:ViolatingName"/> 
    <xs:complexType name="ViolatingName">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="prova" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="AdditionalInfos" type="AdditionalInfos"/>
    <xs:complexType name="AdditionalInfos">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="ViolatingName" type="tns:ViolatingName"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Binding**

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../path/of/your.xsd">

            <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AdditionalInfos']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='ViolatingName']">
                <property name="aaa" />
            </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

**Generated Class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AdditionalInfos", propOrder = {
    "aaa",
})
@XmlRootElement
public class AdditionalInfos
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 12343L;
    @XmlElement(name = "ViolatingName", required = true)
    protected ViolatingName aaa;
```