# wsimport Two declarations cause a collision

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

I am trying to use wsimport on https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/users.svc?wsdl. Here is the wsimport I am using.

```
wsimport -B-XautoNameResolution -d C:\temp -extension -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all -keep -verbose -XadditionalHeaders -Xnocompile https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/users.svc?wsdl
```

And here is the error.

parsing WSDL...

```
    [WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "EndpointReference" 
    (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing") line 1 of 
    https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/users.svc?wsdl
    [ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class. 
    line 1 of https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd3
    [ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration. 
    line 1 of https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd3
    [ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class. 
    line 1 of https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd2
    [ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration. 
    line 1 of https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd2
    Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException 
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:129)at
    com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2283)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:183)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at 
    com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159) at 
    com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
```

I searched around on StackOverflow and found [wsimport - Two declarations cause a collision, same line given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883790/wsimport-two-declarations-cause-a-collision-same-line-given) but this is from 4 years ago and I don't know if the resolution is still applicable. The recommendation was to remove the -p which I did but I am still receiving the error above. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I can plug the wsdl into SoapUI and generate testing stubs but I just can't seem to get over the wsimport hump.

*UPDATE 1*
I have tried using schema binding as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd0">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.users" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd1">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.serialization"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd2">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv2"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>    
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd3">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv1"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd4">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.arrays"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd5">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.location"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd6">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv3"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Here is the updated wsimport.

```
wsimport -b "C:\temp\Customization.xml" -B-XautoNameResolution -d C:\temp -extension -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all -keep -verbose -XadditionalHeaders -Xnocompile https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/users.svc?wsdl
```

I am still receiving that same error message as above.

*UPDATE 2*
Finally solved with the following updates.

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd2">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv2"/>
        <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jxb:typeName suffix="Type" /> 
            <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/> 
        </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>    
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd3">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv1"/>
        <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jxb:typeName suffix="Type" /> 
            <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/> 
        </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I'm not 100% sure this is the best or even correct resolution but the errors are gone and code is generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the final wsimport I used.

```
wsimport -b "C:\temp\Customization.xml" -B-XautoNameResolution -d C:\temp -extension -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all -keep -verbose -XadditionalHeaders -Xnocompile https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/users.svc?wsdl
```

And here is the custom binding xml. I hope this helps someone else. This was a real pain to solve!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd0">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.users" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd1">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.serialization"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd2">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv2"/>
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:typeName suffix="Type" /> 
                <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/> 
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>    
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd3">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv1"/>
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:typeName suffix="Type" /> 
                <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/> 
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd4">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.arrays"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd5">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.location"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://api.sendwordnow.com/webservices/v3/Users.svc?xsd=xsd6">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.datacontractsv3"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: I am having similar problem, but I can't figure out how did you solved ? Can you give me some description of the solution ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your solution in an effort to get wsimport working on another wsdl I'm having trouble with. I got this error: `[ERROR] file:/C:/temp/.xml.accessExternalSchema=all is unreachable`

wsimport version is 2.2.9

Comment: Found out why I was getting that error. It doesn't work in PowerShell.