# How to rename an element in a wsdl using CXF WSDL2Java?

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am trying to parse a 3rd party WSDL file (Which i can't change) to Java using CXFs WSDL2Java but I am running into an exception (Shown below). This exact same exception is repeated 7 times. They are completely identical. I am guessing the problem is in the xsd, where I find several snippets like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="CCTUserDetails">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CCTLogin" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CCTServerName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Domain" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Enabled" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="UserName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="CCTUserDetails" nillable="true" type="tns:CCTUserDetails"/>
```

Investigating the error, it seems that I need to do some custom JaxB mapping but I have absolutely no idea of how to do that. Can someone show me how to rename either the complextype or element using an external JaxB mapping file with CXFs WSDL2Java to get around this error? 
I am using the cxf-codegen-plugin with maven.

```
[ERROR] http://ccsbsrv11.tdk.dk/WebServices/OpenInterfaces/soap.svc?xsd=xsd0 [0:0]: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://ccsbsrv11.tdk.dk/WebServices/OpenInterfaces/soap.svc?xsd=xsd0; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate(ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:191)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate(PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:270)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:169)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:284)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:459)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:726)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:270)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:415)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] http://ccsbsrv11.tdk.dk/WebServices/OpenInterfaces/soap.svc?xsd=xsd0 [0:0]: (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://ccsbsrv11.tdk.dk/WebServices/OpenInterfaces/soap.svc?xsd=xsd0; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate(ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:193)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate(PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:270)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:169)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:284)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:459)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:726)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:270)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:415)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: Why are you defining twice the type `CCTUserDetails`? (once as a complex type and once as an element)

Comment: I am not, it is a 3rd party WSDL

Comment: Then maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422253/xjc-two-declarations-cause-a-collision-in-the-objectfactory-class ?

Comment: I did spot that earlier, which is actually what sent me down the road of jaxb bindings, but i have no experience with them and i don't really have anywhere to start

Comment: Here another related stack overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883790/wsimport-two-declarations-cause-a-collision-same-line-given

Comment: I saw what one too, and it doesn't seem to hit home either. The problem there seems to be that the OP attempted to force several similarly named types into the same package. I am not doing anything of that sort, my XSD's are simply cursed. I really believe i need to go the XSD bindings route, I just have no idea how to do that.

Comment: If you go that way, I cannot help you

Answer (score 0):

try changing your XSD to

```
<xs:complexType name="CCTUserDetailsType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CCTLogin" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CCTServerName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Domain" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Enabled" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="UserName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="CCTUserDetails" nillable="true" type="CCTUserDetailsType"/>
```

Comment: The XSDs are 3. party. I cannot change them